Spring's @Value Annotation always get null
I'm a beginner of Java and Spring framework, I'm learning how to configure an application without spring boot. In my @Configuration Class, I have these codes:
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.example")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 ...
   @Value("${app.person.url}")
    private String propertyValue;
...
}

and in resources/application.properties, I have written app.person.url = "jdbc:h2:\\test\\h2test". I write a method to read this value:
public record Person(String url) {
}

    @Bean
    public Person getFromProperty() {
        return new Person(propertyValue);
    }

And in my controller, I wrote a method mapping to localhost:8080/data to get the Person Bean:
    @GetMapping("/data")
    public Person data() {
        return context.getBean(Person.class);
    }

However, when I accessed to localhost:8080/data, I always get a person with a null url:
{
    "url": null
}

Why did this happen? And what can I do to solve this problem? I have uploaded the code to github:https://github.com/dzkd2019/SpringMvcDemo/tree/master
I tried to add a static bean of type PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, but this not works.

You are passing an empty context to the DispatcherServlet so it will just contruct a new instance of the person instead of creating one. Just ditch the ContextLoaderListener stuff and pass in the context directly to the DispatcherServlet. Or use the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and specify the rootConfigClasses and leave the servletConfigClasses as null.

I've tried both methods, but neither of them solved the issue; accessing localhost:8080/data still returns person with null field. Here is the code I have modified.
    `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();`

    `context.register(WebConfig.class);`

   `servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));`


    `var appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet((context)));`

    `appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);`

    `appServlet.addMapping("/");`


Or I tried to add a class extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and delete the configuration codes in the WebApplicationInitializer, but this modification didn't work either. I uploaded the revised code to the revised branch. https://github.com/dzkd2019/SpringMvcDemo/tree/revised
